# Can we be sure that Rust will optimize out clone() if it is going to dropped immediately?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

Obviously whether it does or doesn't will not matter in 99% of cases, but just to help silly anxious developers like me sleep well at night:

Let's say you have code that calls a complex library function that returns a mutable reference, that you then want to return. It also happens that this reference is to a type that implements Clone. So to avoid refactoring too much, you do something like this:

```
fn common_behavior(specs: Specs) -> ClonableThing {

    let mut intermediate_thing = IntermediateThing::new(specs);

    let clonable_thing: &mut ClonableThing = intermediate_thing.create_mut_ref_to_thing();

    // Will the clone here be reliably optimized out?
    std::mem::replace(clonable_thing, clonable_thing.clone())
}
```

Obviously the replacement value generated by `clonable_thing.clone()` will be dropped immediately when `intermediate_thing` and everything else goes out of scope, but can we expect that the cloning operation itself will not occur? This is assuming that `intermediate_thing` is a fairly complex struct but that the cloning itself is just generated by a `#[derive(Clone)]`.

Comment: Why this monster instead of the equivalent and much shorter `clonable_thing.clone()`?

Comment: `#[derive(Clone)]` can execute arbitrary code, because it just code the _fields'_ `Clone`.

Comment: Note that if `ClonableThing` implements `Default`, `std::mem::take(clonable_thing)` is _probably_ going to be faster. Or else if it has some cheap-to-make-default, then `std::mem::replace(clonable_thing, cheap_to_make_default)`.

Comment: Those are some really good points. The idea with the ```replace``` (or ```take```, thanks for the tip!) was to hopefully get the original ```ClonableThing``` without explicitly copying it. Of course, not that it would matter most of the time.

Comment: It only matters if `Clone` changes some data, which will be really weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not guaranteed by the compiler. In particular, your call to `clone()` could have side-effects, in which case the compiler is not allowed to optimize it away.

In practice, if your implementation of `clone()` is simple (which is almost always the case), it will generally be optimized away, but the only way to be 100% certain is to disassemble the code.

Comment: Worth noting: Clone isn't special in this regard. There's no special guarentees that clone gets optimized more than any other function.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Actually, `Clone` _is_ quite a bit special because there are various containers in the standard library that replace calls to `clone()` with a bitwise copy (via specialization) where `T: Copy`.

Comment: Learned something new today! Is there any documentation on those containers that replace ```clone()```?

Comment: @Dunedubby Not really, except that [the `Clone` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#how-can-i-implement-clone) says that if `T: Copy`, `clone()` must be equivalent to a bitwise copy. But you can look at the implementation, eg. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#400.